# Try send message to test if FCM works but the app crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to build a Firebase chat app and wanted to test if FCM works. Tried testing the notification function by sending a cloud messaging from the firebase console but the app crash in all the devices.

This is the error retrive from the logcat

> 06-30 16:11:07.783 26794-26794/com.example.ryzeng.firebasechat
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ryzeng.firebasechat, PID: 26794
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzad()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzan; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzan; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.firebase.iid.zzan' appears in
>   /data/app/com.example.ryzeng.firebasechat-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>           at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzb(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3366)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Or you can try contacting Firebase support.

Answer (score 8):

In your project files , in file **build.gradle** ("Module: app")
change version of firebase messaging to last version like :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Work for me**

**When i Update firebase messaging dependency**

**from**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

**to**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you implement 2 or more Firebase with different versions.

So it's better to give same version to all firebase's implementation.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
```